# ionic 4 angular route observable not working once I leave the view and re-enter

Tags: angular, angular-router, ionic4

I have a setup where in a single ionic 4 page, I am showing multiple items based on query params. Consider a list with different categories and onclick, I will update the query params.

So I have an observable

```js
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((data) => {
  console.error('in subscribe', data);
  this.updateCategories(data['params']);
});
```

This works fine when I first come to page. But when I navigate to some other page and then come back, the `console.error` from this above code stops working.

If I am correct, observables on route are self destroyed by angular (I also tried to unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy and then subscribe again). And when I come back again, it should subscribe to the route's queryParamMap and work as before.

I am using ionic 4 beta 12 with Angular 6.0.8. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm also facing same problem and cannot find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you subscribing in OnInit method or somewhere else? I tried your sample code and it is working fine on my local:

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { ParentComponent } from './parent.component';
import { NewRouteComponent } from './new-route.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ParentComponent },
  { path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent },
  { path: 'newroute', component: NewRouteComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `<a routerLink="../newroute">Click here</a>`,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe((data) => {
      console.error('in subscribe', data);
    });
  }

}
```

new-route.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-route',
  template: `<p>new-route works!</p>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>`,
  styleUrls: ['./new-route.component.css']
})
export class NewRouteComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  goBack() {
    this.activatedRoute.navigate(['./parent']);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried with ngOnInit, constructor and in ionic ionViewWillEnter, ionViewDidEnter. Not at the same time of course, separately. The code setup is similar, but it doesn't work. Once I come back to parent, it just stops the console log from inside the subscribe. I will try to put an example on github.